# What difference does it make to put an annotation @Lob or not?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

There is a request table in my database.
Here is its structure

[image]

Usually I created the entity with my hands, but this time I decided to generate it from the database. Here's what I got

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "request")
public class Request
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "body")
    private String body;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 10000)
    private String description;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "headers")
    private String headers;

    @Column(name = "http_method", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String httpMethod;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "path_variables")
    private String pathVariables;

    @Column(name = "port")
    private Integer port;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "query_params")
    private String queryParams;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false)
    private String url;
```

I noticed that a strange annotation **@Lob** appeared.
I've never seen her before. I decided to Google what it means and why to put it.
I found a lot of answers and they all said that this annotation is needed so that Hibernate understands that there may be a big object here.

But it seems to me that this annotation does nothing. After all, regardless of whether it is worth it or not, everything works the same?

> What is it for?

Comment: Maybe it makes a difference in other database products.  After all the point of this type of ORM code is to be product neutral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, your entity generation tool just marked with `@Lob` all the columns that don't have the length specified - most likely just to make sure that whatever data you put into them it will fit.
(Say, in Oracle maximum BLOB/CLOB size is `(4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE initialization parameter (8 TB to 128 TB)`)

As for the `@Lob` itself, here's what [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/latest/javax/persistence/Lob.html) says:

> Specifies that a persistent property or field should be persisted as a large object to a database-supported large object type.
> Portable applications should use the Lob annotation when mapping to a database Lob type. The Lob annotation may be used in conjunction with the Basic annotation or the ElementCollection annotation when the element collection value is of basic type. A Lob may be either a binary or character type.

> The Lob type is inferred from the type of the persistent field or property, and except for string and character-based types defaults to Blob.

The common usecase for binary lobs (BLOBs) is storing some binary file content in the database, say an image, and for the character lobs (CLOBs) - large texts documents.